# How do i prevent subfolders access via anonymous http-url-path inspite of password-protected aspx.default file on parent-folder?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, html

Could anyone help with info on how to keep files and folders free from anonymous http access, besides what i've already done.  The aspx project-folder gateway/default file is an aspx.net/vb.net password protected web-page, which works well. But if anyone knows and types the full url path to any html-file or subfolder within, they still gain access (bypassing the aspx password page).

Here's what i've done so far====

---Utilizing settings of my IIS-7 server, i've attempted rendering the subfolders not accessible to anonymous browsers, but then after doing so my aspx password page becomes ineffective in redirecting to the subfolders and htl files within. After putting in correct password on my aspx password page, i run into a 404-Unauthorized access error msg, which means even password authorized access is disabled when i turn off anonymous access to the subfolders.

Could this have anything to do with the fact that my aspx password entry page submit-button is NOT pointing to another aspx page but is rather, pointing to HTML pages within the subfolder?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that using a Web.sitemap xml configuration file can help you.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178428.aspx

Comment: Scott thanks so much for your time and feedback on my last question.